# How do I change my default local directory (for psftp)?

Tags: windows, putty, psftp

How do I change my default local directory in PSFTP? I know how to open the application and change my local directory with `lcd C:\where\I\want\to\go`, but I want every session to automatically run that command, or not need that command run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to configure `psftp` to start in a directory of your choice. `psftp` starts in its start up directory. So you will have to change that.

If you start `psftp` via a shortcut, change the shortcut startup directory.

If you start `psftp` by typing its name on Windows commandline, you can create a batch file that does `cd` and then starts `psftp`.

```
cd C:\where\I\want\to\go
C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\psftp.exe" %*
```

If you put the path to the batch file to `PATH` before the path to the PuTTY, typing `psftp` will start the batch file instead of `psftp.exe`.

Comment: I got it working by making a copy of psftp in my desired directory and then using that as the shortcut target. Thank you.